# Discrete Math - Counting Integer Solutions to Inequality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality

I'm trying to find the number of integer solutions to

> $x + y + z + w \le 20$ where $x \ge 1$, $y \ge 2$, $z \ge 3$ and $w \ge 4$.

So far I did $x-1 + y-2 + z-3 + w-4 \le 10$. I believe if it were to be equal to $10$ then there would be ${13\choose10}=286$ solutions but I'm not sure if I did that correctly or how to count with the inequality without overcounting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you've written looks correct to me. The usual trick with an inequality is to introduce an extra variable whose job is to take up all the slack: $x+y+z+w+v=20$ with $v\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done. You are right, for $10$ is how you are saying. Now, what about for $9$? $8$? In general, just add
$$\sum _{i=0}^{10}\left ( \text{# of solutions to }a+b+c+d=i\right ),$$
where $a=x-1,b=y-2,\cdots$ This is equivalent to construct a variable $e\geq 0$ such that
$a+b+c+d+e=10$ as hinted by Jaap Scherphuis in the comments.
Both results will be the same and the connection of the formulas comes from the [Hockey-Stick identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)